# Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference MVC5 Razor View

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have my ViewModel

```
 public class FestivalViewModel
    {
        public virtual DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<EventGroup> EventGroups { get; set; }
    }
```

I create and populate the view model in my controller's result:

```
 var festivalViewModel = new FestivalViewModel();
 festivalViewModel.Date = festival.Events.First().StartsOn;
 festivalViewModel.EventGroups = festival.GetEventGroups();
```

My GetEventGroups() method is

```
  public virtual IList<EventGroup> GetEventGroups()
    {
      return this.Events.GroupBy(each => each.StartsOn.Date)
             .Select(result => 
                new EventGroup 
                { 
                   Date = result.Key, 
                   Events = result.ToList() 
                 })
               .ToList();
    }
```

In my Razor view, I'm trying to go through the populated data and display it:

```
@foreach (var eventGroup in this.Model.EventGroups)
    {
            <p><strong>@eventGroup.Date</strong></p>
    }
```

The problem is, @eventGroup.Date throws me the exception:

> *Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference*

Any help on what could be causing this would be highly appreciated. I looked through the existing answers, but none of them seem to be related to this (or I just happen to be blind)

EDIT:
Turns out what was causing it was this

```
id="checkbox-table-@ViewBag.MissingViewBagElement.IndexOf(eventGroup)"
```

located on a different part of the game, way further than the line our beloved debugger was showing

Comment: ``eventGroup`` is null most probably, can you show your action code of controller

Comment: What are the values of this.Events ?

Comment: this.Events returns a list of events. I've checked - both .Events and .EventGroups do indeed contain data in them, the values of neither are null

Comment: Comment out that `@foreach` loop and see if you still get an error. That error can be a red herring, in that something else in the view is wrong and the exception is being thrown in the wrong place.

Comment: might be a stupid question but have you returned the model in your action method ie. return View(festivalViewModel); ?   since the reason for the error is that your model is missing.

Comment: @Andreas yeah, I'm returning the festivalViewModel - return base.View(festivalViewModel);

Comment: and the Date has a value?

Comment: @Andreas - Yes, it does indeed; Jason - Done, no error with that commented out

Comment: if you inspect the eventGroup inside the view, is it null ?

Comment: @MihaiTibrea - No, the eventGroup does contain data and has a Date record with the correct date

Comment: That is really strange ! Is the model reference correctly inside your view ?

Comment: Found what was causing it, adding an edit now

Comment: @JasonEvans I believe your answer was closest to the truth, I may have just executed it poorly.